# How to select different dropdown menus with constant class jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a HTML form that has multiple drop down menus that contain multiple classes (but 1 one of them is constant). I call a jQuery function once the user has changed a value in any of the menus. However, anytime I try to change the 2nd or 3rd menu, the function still only returns the id and class of the first menu. How do I get the id/class of the 2nd or 3rd menu?

HTML:

```
     <!-- first dropdown menu-->
     <select id="class1Grade" class="section1 grades">
             <option value=" "></option>
             <option value="A">A</option>
             <option value="B">B</option>
         <option value="C">C</option>
             <option value="D">D</option>
         <option value="F">F</option>
     </select>  

     <!-- second dropdown menu-->
     <select id="class2Grade" class="section2 grades">
             <option value=" "></option>
             <option value="A">A</option>
             <option value="B">B</option>
         <option value="C">C</option>
             <option value="D">D</option>
         <option value="F">F</option>
     </select>  
     <!-- third dropdown menu-->
     <select id="class3Grade" class="section3 grades">
             <option value=" "></option>
             <option value="A">A</option>
             <option value="B">B</option>
         <option value="C">C</option>
             <option value="D">D</option>
         <option value="F">F</option>
     </select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".grades").change(function() {
    var gradeNumber = $(".grades").attr("id"); //if i select the 2nd/3rd menu, it returns "class1Grade" rather than "class2Grade" or "class3Grade"
    var section = $(".grades").attr('class'); //if i select the 2nd/3rd menu, it returns "section1 grades" rather than "section2 grades" or "section3 grades"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$(".grades").change(function() {
    var gradeNumber = $(this).attr("id"); 
    var section = $(this).attr('class'); 
});
```

You need to refer to the proper scope of the `select` element being click using the `$(this)`.

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PBpHj/)

---

or using the HTML DOM property:

```
$(".grades").change(function () {
    var gradeNumber = this.id;
    var section = this.className;
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PBpHj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$(".grades").change(function() {
    var gradeNumber = $(this).attr("id"); //or this.id; better and faster option
    var section = $(this).attr('class'); 
});
```

`this` refers to the current element `changed` in the above code.